# C# User Impersonation not being passed on to sub-processes

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I am trying to impersonate user for all the processes running from a console app. I don't want to start my VisualStudio as that user nor want to keep attaching external process running under that user.

This is what I have tried...

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Environment.UserName: {0}", Environment.UserName); // Prints currently logged-in win username

            ConfigurationManager.GetSection("configuration");                    

            using (var impersonator = new Impersonator())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Environment.UserName: {0}", Environment.UserName); // Prints impersonated username

                var hostAccount = new System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost(typeof(AccountService));  // WCF Service class            
                hostAccount.Open();
            }
        }
```

If I try to inspect value of Environment.UserName inside any method of AccountService class, it always gives me currently logged-in win username instead of impersonated user.

My Impersonator class uses following code to impersonate user.

```
bool returnValue = LogonUser(user, userDomain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref _userHandle);

if (!returnValue)
    throw new ApplicationException("Could not impersonate user");

WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(_userHandle);
_impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();
```

I am trying to achieve something what the following code does but running app in debug mode and without changing any current wcf config.

```
Process.Start("path to exe", "user", ssPwd, "MyDOMAIN");
```

I do understand there is difference between running the whole app as an user and impersonating an user inside app. But just want to see if someone had similar issue and managed to find a solution.

**Edit 1:**

I have tried starting new threads after impersonating a user and they all were running under impersonated user. So new threads do get impersonated context. I guess it has something to do with how wcf host gets started.

Comment: I'm confused - are you saying `hostAccount.Open()` creates a new process but doesn't capture the impersonation context? If so, that's expected. In fact that's happening at the operating system level, not the CLR: by default Windows doesn't capture the SecurityContext (which includes the Identity information) of the calling process or even the calling thread. You'll have to somehow pass the impersonation token to the new process and run `.Impersonate()` _there_.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange 
_"I'm confused - are you saying `hostAccount.Open()` creates a new process but doesn't capture the impersonation context?"_ 
**YES**.

_"by default Windows doesn't capture the SecurityContext (which includes the Identity information) of the calling process or even the calling thread."_ If this is true then it has to be only for impersonated context else `Process.Start("path to exe", "user", ssPwd, "MyDOMAIN");` would had the same issue.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange _"You'll have to somehow pass the impersonation token to the new process and run .Impersonate() there."_ This should work but I have many hosts and other processes getting started from the main method (I have removed rest of the code from the question to make it simple) so don't want to spread impersonation code everywhere.

Comment: Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429(VS.85).aspx. It'll let you start a process using an impersonation token.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Thanks but how it is different than `Process.Start("path to exe", "user", ssPwd, "MyDOMAIN");`? I don't want to pass `lpApplicationName`. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wcfhost.open() always runs under main user identity and not under impersonated identity. So now I am starting my main console app under different user from another console app and attaching debugger to it and it works.

I have copied my code below if it helps anyone.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using EnvDTE80;
using Process = System.Diagnostics.Process;

namespace StartService
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var secure = new SecureString();
            foreach (var c in "password-from-config")
            {
                secure.AppendChar(c);
            }

            Process process = null;

            try
            {
                process = Process.Start(@"C:\Test Projects\WcfServiceTest\WcfServiceTest\bin\Debug\WcfServiceTest.exe",
                    "TestUser", secure, "DomainName");

                Attach(GetCurrent());

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (process != null && !process.HasExited)
                {
                    process.CloseMainWindow();
                    process.Close();
                }    
            }
        }

        public static void Attach(DTE2 dte)
        {
            var processes = dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses;
            foreach (var proc in processes.Cast<EnvDTE.Process>().Where(proc => proc.Name.IndexOf("WcfServiceTest.exe") != -1))
                proc.Attach();
        }

        internal static DTE2 GetCurrent()
        {
            var dte2 = (DTE2)Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0"); // Specific to VS2013

            return dte2;
        }
    }
}
```